# How to set a specific text with the word in the list view?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a list view by adding specific courses on the main page in Android app.

When I click on one of the `ListView` items (courses), I will go to a new page using intent. In that new page I would like the text to be replaced with the name of the course that I clicked on.

Is there any example showing how I would do this? I cannot show all my code cause there are multiple pages and fragments.

Comment: You can send string of course name in intent. Like, intent.putExtra("course_name","abc");.                 Now, in new page you can get that extra string from intent. String name = getIntent.getStringExtra("course_name", "");

Comment: Awesome i got it. Thanks